# React-Webcam (npm package) Recording Audio but Mute playback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webcam

I am trying to use the react-webcam from [npm here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webcam) in order to be able to record video with audio. I want the audio to be muted whilst recording but be included when saving a recording.

The webcam is set as follows:

```
const videoConstraints = {
  width: 640,
  height: 480,
  facingMode: "user",
};

const audioConstraints = {
  suppressLocalAudioPlayback: true,
  noiseSuppression: true,
  echoCancellation: true,
};

const ReactWebcam = () => {
  return (
    <div className="webcam" style={{ width: 640 }}>
      <Webcam
        audio={true}
        height={100 + "%"}
        width={100 + "%"}
        screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
        videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
        audioConstraints={audioConstraints}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And this is used on a button click to Record and Stop the video recording:

```
  const handleStartCaptureClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    setCapturing(true);
    mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(webcamElement.current.stream, {
      mimeType: "video/webm",
    });
    mediaRecorderRef.current.addEventListener(
      "dataavailable",
      handleDataAvailable
    );
    mediaRecorderRef.current.start();
  }, [webcamElement, setCapturing, mediaRecorderRef, handleDataAvailable]);

  const handleStopCaptureClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
    setCapturing(false);
  }, [mediaRecorderRef, setCapturing]);
```

I have set the Webcam property `audio` to `true` and audio seems to feedback through the speakers from the mic. I have taken a look at the `audioConstraints` but have found very little luck here. I have found three properties for these **audioConstraints** whilst digging through the **react-webcam.d.ts** file however no combination of these properties seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this was quite simple in the end. This Webcam component ultimately renders a `video` html element and therefore accepts its properties. Therefore adding the video element property `muted={true}` to the webcam component along with the `audio={true}` resulted in Audio being recorded but no play-back as I am recording. Exactly what I was after. Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: How would record a video with no audio?

Comment: set audio prop to false `audio={false}`